# Refit Xamarin Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException expecting JSON receiving HTML instead Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException

Tags: c#, xamarin, json.net, refit

I am receiving an error when calling an API and it returns HTML(error occured) instead of JSON which causes the Xamarin app to crash. I realize this is not ideal for the API to return this, but what I am working with.

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

IMyApi Class

`Task<ApiResponse<ContentModel>> GetContentModel();`

MyService Class

```
            try
            {
                var response = await MyAPI.GetContentModel();

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return response.Content;
                }

                HandleApiErrors(response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(TAG, ex.ToString());
            }
```

Exception

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue () [0x002b3] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () [0x0004c] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent () [0x00000] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, System.Boolean hasConverter) [0x0004a] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x000db] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00054] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T] (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader) [0x00000] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0
> at Refit.NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer.DeserializeAsync[T] (System.Net.Http.HttpContent content) [0x000a6] in /*/Refit/NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer.cs:53
> at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation.DeserializeContentAsync[T] (System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage resp, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content) [0x002a8] in /*/Refit/RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:314
> at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation+<>c__DisplayClass14_0`2[T,TBody].<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0 (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, System.Threading.CancellationToken ct, System.Object[] paramList) [0x002be] in /_/Refit/RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:258  at ContentService.GetContent () [0x0002e] in /Users/ContentService.cs:28 : ContentService Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0. at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue () [0x002b3] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () [0x0004c] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent () [0x00000] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, System.Boolean hasConverter) [0x0004a] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x000db] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00054] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T] (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader) [0x00000] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0  at Refit.NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer.DeserializeAsync[T] (System.Net.Http.HttpContent content) [0x000a6] in /_/Refit/NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer.cs:53  at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation.DeserializeContentAsync[T] (System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage resp, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content) [0x002a8] in /_/Refit/RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:314  at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation+<>c__DisplayClass14_0`2[T,TBody].b__0 (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, System.Threading.CancellationToken ct, System.Object[] paramList) [0x002be] in /_/Refit/RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:258

Comment: use try/catch to handle the excepton

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  And since you haven't posted any code I have no idea what specifically you are doing.

Comment: I already tried that, it happens outside of the call, internal to Refit and how it deserializes the response

Comment: if Refit is throwing an exception you should be able to catch it.

Comment: please edit your post and format the code so it is readable, don't just stuff it into a comment

Comment: Exception is thrown at `var response = await MyAPI.GetContent();` but not able to be catch with exception handling

Comment: Looks like it might be occuring on line:314 in RequestBuilderImplementation
`result = await serializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(content);`
which is not bubbling up the exception

Comment: Why not post the code for `MyAPI.GetContent();` -- You probably have to specify an `Accept` header with value `application/json`. Either that or you are calling the endpoint wrong.

Comment: @Andy it is already posted above, just had to edit it.`Task<ApiResponse<ContentModel>> GetContentModel();` And the endpoint is the correct one, unfortunately the server returns and HTML error page on errors and also if not connected to VPN you get a HTML DNS error page.

Comment: Android handles it gracefully, iOS crashes at the AppDelegate. Is there a way to wrap all unhandled exceptions in iOS? @Jason